# ovs-ofctl dl_dst not equal to

Tags: arp, opendaylight, openflow

I'm trying to direct non-broadcast arps to my controller.

Basically I wanted to do something like this:

```
sudo ovs-ofctl add-flow br0 dl_type=0x0806,dl_dst!=ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff,priority=101,action=CONTROLLER:65535
```

However there is no such thing as `!=` for the `dl_dst`

I'd also like to create another flow that floods all broadcast arps to every port (except the one it was sent on)

Thank you in advance for your help!